# How to move a tab back to the parent Window in Safari 5.0?

Tags: windows, browser, safari, tabs, safari-5

I dragged a new tab out to create a window. Now how do I re-merge it with the previous window?

There seems to be no way of doing it. (Except create a new dummy tab, drag this one to the previous window, close the window with the dummy tab).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit Ctrl-Shift-T to always show the tab bar, then you can drag the tabs between windows.